# Windows 10 Taskbar and other components not working correctly

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, taskbar, system-restore, cortana

After a recent Windows10 update I noticed various functions of the Taskbar not working properly anymore. Upon some investigation I noticed even more Problems.

- The Windows button in the Taskbar is not working (left & right click)
- The Windows key on the keyboard does not open the startmenu either (other functions like win+e work properly)
- I can only left click application symbols (to start them), right clicking does nothing
- Shift-click (left & right) on the application symbols works
- Right clicking on the Taskbar opens the context menu but I can not open the "settings" menu (after clicking on the entry the menu closes and nothing happens)
- Left clicking on the Battery, Wifi, Volume, Date or Info-center icon does nothing
- Right clicking on these icons however does work
- For any other (running) application icons (e.g. hidden icons) left and right click is working

When further looking into it I noticed that some settings like the folder display options had changed and opening .bmp files with the regular windows-photo viewer now yields an error.
[Interface not supported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0fyo.png)

As I wanted to create a new user to see whether the problem persisted through different users I received another error message.
[Class not registered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzFEt.png)
I receive the same error when trying to access "ms-settings:".

Unfortunately my only restorepoint is after the update.

When starting in safe mode I get the error message "sihost.exe - system warning - Unknown Hard Error" and all of the above also applies.

So I tried various "solutions":

- Restart Explorer through the Taskmanager
- Stopping the "Tile Data model server" process
- List item
- Deleting all files from

  %localappdata%\TileDataLayer\Database\

  vedatamodel.edb, vedatamodel.jfm, EDB.log could not be removed
- Using startmenu.diagcab it found that

  "Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost"

  and

  "Microsoft.Windows.Cortana"

  were not correctly installed but failed to install them.
- Using the following PowerShell script (from a cmd with admin rights)

  Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
- Running "sfc /scannow" - but not finding anything
- Countless restarts ;)

Neither of which seemed to have any effect.

I'm using Version 1607 (Build 14393.187)

All the of those problems appear for every user.

Comment: Which build are you using? The Anniversary Update seems to have fixed many issues including Start menu / shellexperiencehost problems.

Comment: I'm using Version 1607 (Build 14393,187)

Comment: See if this method works [SOLVED: Fix Windows 10 Start Button Does Nothing in 10 Minutes](http://www.urtech.ca/2015/09/solved-fix-windows-10-start-button-does-nothing-in-10-minutes/)

Comment: Thanks for the link! I tried that but since the problem appears for other users too it did nothing. I also tried safe boot and got another [error](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/88731734/W1SUQ/HardError.png) (sihost.exe - system warning - Unknown Hard Error)

Comment: Since there are additional issues involved (ms-settings: URI and Photos registration missing), I'd do a reinstall or in-place upgrade by downloading the 14393.187 ISO from Microsoft, mounting it and running setup.exe. In-place repair preserves your files/data and programs.

Comment: Thanks! I used the "MediaCreationTool" from Microsoft and selected "Upgrade this PC". Now everything is working fine.

Comment: Gr8. Glad that helped.